# Using Armstrong's Axioms to prove that an attribute is a super key

Tags: functional-dependencies, database-theory

So I am given the relation
`R (A, B, C, D, E, F)`
with
`FD = {AB -> C, AD->B, C->B, F-> AD, F-> E}`
and I need to use Armstrong's Axioms to prove `F` is a super key.

I understand Armstrong's Axioms (to a basic extent), but I am not sure how to use them with this application. Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use Armstrong's axioms to prove that the given set of FDs implies F->ABCDEF.

The first axiom to apply is that of transitivity, it seems to me.